# Delete an object from another class

Tags: python, oop, pyqt

I created two different classes, and I need to delete an object in one class, from the other class.

This is part of the code:

```
class A(self):
  def __init__:
    #Some stuff in here

    self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

  def createObject(self):
    plot = Matplotlist()     #This is a matplotlib figure
    self.splitter.addwidget(plot)

class B(self):
  def __init__(self):
    #Some stuff in here

  def deleteObject(self):
    delete_splitter = ?????????
```

How can I access the `self.splitter` in class `A`, from class `B`?

Comment: `self.splitter` is an instance attribute.

Comment: In order to access the internal instance names you need a reference to that instance. `deleteObject` could just take the instance created from `a = A()` as an argument and do whatever it needs with it.

Comment: @Jim thank you for your answer. Do you mean: deleteObject(self, self.splitter) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I meant in the comment is something like this:

Given two classes `A`, `B` where `class A` has an `__init__` method that assigns an attribute `val` to instances created from that class:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val  # assign val to instance variable

    # other methods defined here..
```

`class B` can define a method `deleteObject` that takes an *argument* for an *instance* of `class A` and deletes the attribute contained in it (i.e `val`):

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize things

    def deleteObject(self, obj):
        # delete the attribute 'val' from object
        del object.val
```

You can use this method by *instantiating* `class A` with an assigned `val`:

```
a = A("value")
a.val  # prints value
```

and then passing the instance to the method `deleteObject` of an instance of `B`:

```
b = B()
b.deleteObject(a)
```

Now if you try accessing `a.val` you'll get an `AttributeError` indicating that the instance has no attribute with the name `val`; it has been deleted:

```
a.val
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-eef8eac9d06d> in <module>()
----> 1 a.val

AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'val'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now understand more. Thank you again for your well detailed answer.

Comment: Is there a way I can delete the object itself and not only one of its attributes?

Comment: @NikhilCSB `del objName` deletes the name for that object. If no other references to it exist, it will, at some point, get garbage collected. That's as close as you can get to deletion in Python.